IPython how to display display object
IPython display module HTML class, h is display object. and according to official website rich object, it could display by using display.display(). However both statement give object information instead of displaying anything.
  from IPython import display
  ...
  h = display.HTML(html)
  display.display(h)
  print(h)

output:
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>


I think you need to write html code to display something.

    from IPython import display
    h = display.HTML('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>')
    display.display(h)

